# Use golang to achieve python's timer

Tags: python, go, timer

**Python:**

```
with Timer() as t :
          // TODO a lot

print "scan all disks,cost:%s secs" % t.secs
```

Now,how to use `golang` to achieve this?

I had google this but I can not find any answers I want.

Why am I post my questions in here and then got downvote?

Thank you your help!!!

Comment: I would imagine your question is downvoted because it's very poorly constructed. You haven't shown any effort at all to answer your own question. You should always show what your current code looks like. From your question, it seems you may not even _have_ code, and are asking others to do your work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a function that accepts a function, runs it and prints the time:

```
import (
  "time"
  "fmt"
)

func TimeIt(f func(), description string) {
   start := time.Now()
   f()
   fmt.Printf("Running %s took %v\n", description, time.Since(start))
}
```

And then trigger it like so:

```
func main() {
    TimeIt(doSomething, "Doing something")
}
```

Or just sprinkle it on pieces of code as a closure:

```
TimeIt(func() {
     do()
     some()
     stuff()
   },
   "whatever")
```

Comment: You mean `TimeIt(doSomething, "Doing something")` (without calling `doSomething`)?

Comment: yea, my Go is rusty, I've been doing almost entirely C this past year...

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this in go is to define a timer function and use the defer statement to call it when the function returns.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func timer(start time.Time, description string) {
    fmt.Printf("%s took %s\n", description, time.Since(start))
}


func main() {
    func() {
        defer timer(time.Now(), "scan all disks")
        // TODO: alot
    }()
    // OUTPUT: scan all disks took 0s
}
```

You can measure the time of specific commands by wrapping them into an anonymous function (see above) or you measure the time of a function by simply putting the defer statement at its top, e.g.

```
func foo() {
    defer timer(time.Now(), "foo")
    // ...
}
// OUTPUT: foo took 0s
```